# Font Awesome with bootstrap 3 not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

This is my header where i've added font awesome as stated at the homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Custom Font awesome -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"
</head>
```

And try testing font awesome with adding

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x pull-left"></i> Font Awesome<br>Version 4.0.3
</a>
```

But the result is: none of the font awesome specific typography or icons. It seems like font awesome will not surpress the bootstrap code. Anyone can help?

Comment: your bootstrap link is broken. can you provide a fiddle to reproduce this issue? what output do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have any problems with the following example, which is basically a combination of the two snippets you posted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Custom Font awesome -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>    

<body>
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x pull-left"></i> Font Awesome<br>Version 4.0.3
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

As Michal remarked, your version had an open link tag for the Bootstrap style-sheet. The only change I did, was loading Bootstrap from a CDN as well (since I didn't have a local copy handy).

However, the example even worked when the link tag wasn't closed, but that might depend on the browser used. Did you get any errors in your console (e.g. missing components?)

Comment: Yes, your code works very well. Thanks. I'll advise for those just coming to this thread to read the 's' in fas fa-ICON NAME and let it be fa fa-ICON NAME. I decided to state this because though the code above worked for me but simply because i didn't remove the 's' in fas i couldn't get the font to load but a broken font image.

Comment: Also if you copied any code like <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> this from the website. Kindly remove the b at the end. This is bootstrap 3 I really don't know about other versions for now.

Comment: Font Awesome v5 changed the base class from `fa` to `far` (regular), `fas` (solid), and `fab` (brand). The pro version even has some more.